# Dask aggregate value into fixed range with start and end time?

Tags: pandas, range, aggregate, dask

In dask or even pandas how would you go about grouping an dask data frame that has a 3 columns of time / level / spread into a set of fixed ranges by time.

Time is only used to move one direction.  Like a loop counting up.  So the end result would be start time and end time with high of level, low of level, first value of level and last value of level over the fixed range?  Example

```
12:00:00, 10, 1
12:00:01, 11, 1
12:00:02, 12, 1
12:00:03, 11, 1
12:00:04, 9,  1
12:00:05, 6,  1
12:00:06, 10, 1
12:00:07, 14, 1
12:00:08, 11, 1
12:00:09, 7,  1
12:00:10, 13, 1
12:00:11, 8,  1
```

For a fixed level range of (7).  So level from start to end can not be more than 7 total distance from start to end for each bin of level.  Just because first bin is only 8 difference in time and second is only 2 different in time, this dose not madder one the high to low madders that the total distance from high to low dose not go passed 7 the fixed bin size.  The first bin could have been 5 not 8 for first bin and 200 for next bin not 2 in the example below.  So the First few rows in dask would look something like this.

First Time, Last Time, High Level, Low Level, First Level, Last Level, Spread

```
12:00:00, 12:00:07, 13, 6, 10, 13, 1
12:00:07, 12:00:09, 14, 7, 13, 7, 1
12:00:09, X, 13, 7, X, X, X
```

How could this be aggregated in dask with a fix window of level moving forward in time binning each time level moves above X or equal too high/low with in X or below X?

Comment: Are any of the [rolling operations](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#rolling-operations) of use to you here?

Comment: No because this is not max/min/mean this is a vertical box of X size.  Every time X gets above the fixed bin size then a new vertical box is made.  So X at the start can grow to the down side or all to the upside or some part of up and down to make X.  Rolling dose not cover this.